# Jquery clean two inputs when fill another input

Tags: jquery

I want to clear two fields : initial date and final date if i fill a third form input identified by the car_plate id

I try this jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function()     {        
         $('#car_plate').on('click', function() {    
            $(this).closest('#InitialDate').find('input').val('');
            $(this).closest('#FinalDate').find('input').val('');    
        });            
    });
```

But it did not clean

How can it be done ?

Comment: Can you share your HTML ?

Comment: I imagine this could be due to a miss-understanding of  `closest`, but we won't be able to help much without seeing the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
         $('#car_plate').focus(function() {    
            $(this).closest('#InitialDate').find('input').val('');
            $(this).closest('#FinalDate').find('input').val('');    
        });            
    });
```

Comment: Thats a blind guess.. you don't even know how his HTML looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#car_plate").on("focus", function() {
        $(this).closest('#InitialDate').find('input').val('');
        $(this).closest('#FinalDate').find('input').val('');
    });
});
```